# Updating Me.txtWhatever.Value & DoCmd.Requery for multiple fields at once

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm more looking for advice to shore up some cluttered coding with some ideas to trim it down and make it a little less "spammy".
I have a control (button) that saves a multiple values to multiple columns in a table (one value each column).  It's not so much as an issue as it is that I'm looking for best practices when dealing with multiple repetitive commands on one control

Currently, this is the code I'm using, which isn't BAD so much as I was hoping there was a shorter more effective way to manage what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
On Error GoTo cmdSave_Click_Err

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    MsgBox "Service Record has been saved", vbInformation, ""
    DoCmd.Requery "txtFirstHistory"
    DoCmd.Requery "txtSecondHistory"
    DoCmd.Requery "txtOctoHistory"
    DoCmd.Requery "txtInflatorHistory"
    DoCmd.Requery "txtHPSPGHistory"
    DoCmd.Requery "txtComputerHistory"
    Me.txtFirstNotes.Value = ""
    Me.txtSecondNotes.Value = ""
    Me.txtOctoNotes.Value = ""
    Me.txtInflatorNotes.Value = ""
    Me.txtHPSPGNotes.Value = ""
    Me.txtComputerNotes.Value = ""
cmdSave_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

cmdSave_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume cmdSave_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

Is there a method to accomplishing this with fewer lines of code?

Comment: I don't understand your code. What is `DoCmd.Requery "txtX"` supposed to do? You only need to requery a control (combobox / listbox) when its row source changes. -- If this is a bound form, you should rather move to a new record instead of setting all values to "" (which would edit the current record).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think that was important so I left it out of the post.  All the `txtWhateverNotes.Value` boxes are unbound textboxes which, `AfterUpdate` they save the value to a column in the table with similar names (minus the "txt" preface).  The `DoCmd.Requery` lines basically just "reload" those historical comments from the table.  `txtWhateverHistory` is where the column actually displays its data, which is why the `DoCmd.Requery` lines are there.  Hopefully that makes a little more sense.  Brain isn't working all that great this early in the morning, so sorry if I'm being confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a very odd way of doing things, but you may have your reasons.

You can use a loop like this:

```
Dim ctl As Access.Control

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
        ' Instead of relying on ctl.Name you could also use ctl.Tag
        If ctl.Name Like "*History" Then
            ctl.Requery
            ' or DoCmd.Requery ctl.Name
        ElseIf ctl.Name Like "*Notes" Then
            ctl.Value = ""
        End If
    End If
Next ctl
```

Comment: That definitely works, but would you suggest something else to create a history for comments in multiple fields?

Comment: TBH, I haven't really understood what exactly you are achieving with this. I suggest a new question where you describe all relevant parts of the process. Include screenshots of form and design view. @BeardedSith